# Extending bootstrap dialog javascript in separate js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using [Bootstrap Dialog](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.6/js/bootstrap-dialog.js) in one of my project. As what shown in the javascript code, there is a section as shown in the code below.

It is straightforward if i would like to add another customize Bootstrap dialog name Bootstrap.customSuccess in the js file itself. However, I intend to add it in another js file as I don't want to tampered the original js file.

I just add the following part to external file and it works. But i am not sure if there is any bad consequence if i add it directly in external file

**Original**

```js
/* ================================================
     * For lazy people
     * ================================================ */

    /**
     * Shortcut function: show
     *
     * @param {type} options
     * @returns the created dialog instance
     */
    BootstrapDialog.show = function(options) {
        return new BootstrapDialog(options).open();
    };
```

**Add this in external js file instead of inside the original js file**

```js
 BootstrapDialog.customSuccess = function(message, callback) {
        return new BootstrapDialog({
            type: BootstrapDialog.TYPE_SUCCESS,
            message: message
        }).open();
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot image any bad consequences. What is on your mind? I have worked quite a lot with Bootstrap and customizing the CSS and JS. I put all custom stuff in separate files to avoid changing the original Bootstrap source. The benefit of this approach is that you have the original Bootstrap code as fallback.